# Extracting a list of values from column A where column B contains a specific value

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

From the following table:

```
ID     Status
001    Done
002    Done
003    Done
004    Error
005    Done
006    Error
007    Done
008    Done
009    Error
```

I want to extract a list/string of all the IDs with an 'Error'. In other words, a cell which looks like this:

```
004, 006, 009
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the free Microsoft Excel add-In [Power Query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-Microsoft-Power-Query-for-Excel-6e92e2f4-2079-4e1f-bad5-89f6269cd605) (from Excel 2010) to filter and aggregate your IDs with error.

You can transform your data over the UI. However you will need to modify some steps directly in the Advanced Editor.

Here two scripts (you can paste it in the advanced editor. be sure that your table source is calles "Table1"):

The 1st will give you this output: 004, 006, 009

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", type text}, {"Status", type text}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([Status] = "Error")),
    #"Removed Other Columns" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Rows",{"ID"}),
    #"Transposed Table" = Table.Transpose(#"Removed Other Columns"),
    #"List ID" = Table.ToList(#"Transposed Table", Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(", "))
in
    #"List ID"
```

The 2nd will separate even and uneven IDs on two single rows:
009
004, 006

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"ID", type text}, {"Status", type text}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each ([Status] = "Error")),
    #"Added Custom" = Table.AddColumn(#"Filtered Rows", "IsEven", each if Number.IsEven(Number.From([ID])) = true then "even" else "uneven"),

    #"Filtered Even" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([IsEven] = "even")),
    #"Removed Other Columns Even" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Even",{"ID"}),
    #"Transposed Table Even" = Table.Transpose(#"Removed Other Columns Even"),
    #"List Even" = Table.ToList(#"Transposed Table Even", Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(", ")),
    #"Table Even" =Table.FromValue(#"List Even"),

    #"Filtered Uneven" = Table.SelectRows(#"Added Custom", each ([IsEven] = "uneven")),
    #"Removed Other Columns Uneven" = Table.SelectColumns(#"Filtered Uneven",{"ID"}),
    #"Transposed Table Uneven" = Table.Transpose(#"Removed Other Columns Uneven"),
    #"List Uneven" = Table.ToList(#"Transposed Table Uneven", Combiner.CombineTextByDelimiter(", ")),
    #"Table Uneven" =Table.FromValue(#"List Uneven"),

    #"Appended Query" = Table.Combine({#"Table Uneven", #"Table Even"})
in
    #"Appended Query"
```

Give Power Query a try! It's IMO the most powerfull innovation in Excel the last couple years (beside Power Pivot).

Answer (score 0):

OK, I've figured out how to create a *column* of all correct answers: paste this into C1:

=IFERROR(INDEX(A$2:A$10,SMALL(IF($B$2:$B$10="Error",ROW(A$2:A$10)-ROW(A$2)+1),ROWS(A$2:A2))),"")

Then drag down to C10 to see all results, i.e.

```
3
6
9
```

It doesn't concat the result, but this is good enough for me for now.

However, I can't work how to do *two* conditions, for example, cells in column B match "Error" *and* values in column A are even numbers - any ideas?